# How to activate IPv6 on dedicated Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: networking, server, ubuntu-18.04, ipv6, server-administration

everyone!
I am not an expert, but part-time admin; please excuse if the question is too simple:

How can I enable IPv6 on my dedicated Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server?

**The problem: Both the file "/etc/netplan/config.yaml" and "/etc/network/interfaces" are empty on my freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04, unfortunately?!?**

I have chosen an IPv6 address, own a subnet and know the gateway. I just can not enter this anywhere.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an example for /etc/netplan/config.yaml

```html
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 193.33.61.10/24
      - 2a00:7b80:454:2000::xxx/64
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      gateway6: fd32:f949:d949:b66c::1
      accept-ra: true
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 2001:4860:4860::8888]
```